# Using Windows 7 clone an OS X mechanical drive to an SSD

Tags: windows-7, macos, hard-drive, ssd, clone

Situation: client with Apple laptop buys an SSD to upgrade. Installer disc isn't working and waiting another FULL week for "two day shipping" is not really an option.

I can easily hook up their two drives: 500GB mech and 512GB SSD to my Windows rig.

What program will recognize Apple's (Journal?) file system and simply clone the mech drive to the SSD? I'd prefer freeware though something with a free trial that works would be acceptable too.

Comment: Google for "Clonezilla", download and burn ISO, boot from CD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GParted** worked though I had to boot from a Linux Live CD (300MB) and use the boot to RAM option and fill out information about my keyboard and language *twice* though I eventually got it to work (after about six or seven reboots). A better option would be something that does *NOT* require shutting my system down (Windows 7) though for now if someone else asks this question this at least will give me some kind of reasonable option.

http://gparted.org/